# Manipulate list components

Tags: r, list

To generate a new combination of a list of names. I generated a `list` with the following `R` code:

```
names1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
lst <- lapply(1:length(names1), function(x) combn(names1, x))
lst

> list
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "B"  "C"  "C" 

[[3]]
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 
[2,] "B" 
[3,] "C"
```

Now, I would like to turn this list into a vector with the following 7 components, just like this one:

```
newlst <- c("A", "B", "C", "A, B", "A, C", "B, C", "A, B, C")
```

In other words, I would like to combine the values within each column into one component of the new vector. `unlist(lst)` would not work as it produces 12 individual As, Bs, and Cs without any combinations. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I get an error when I try to reproduce your code

Comment: Error on `lapply(...)` hence the error. I corrected it and renamed your names to `names1` since there already is a function called `names`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `combn` takes a function. So if you pass `toString` and `unlist` you will get your output, i.e.

```
unlist(lapply(1:length(names1), function(x) combn(names1, x, toString)))
#[1] "A"       "B"       "C"       "A, B"    "A, C"    "B, C"    "A, B, C"
```

Comment: Amazing! I works perfectly. It took me several hours. Even now,  by reading the document, I don't think I can work it out myself. Many thanks!